# How can i add personal site url to all the users in sharepoint in one shot

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, my-site

I want to add a personal site to all the users(2100) in a quick time.

suggest me the methods.

I am new to SharePoint.

Thanks in [image]advance

Comment: i am looking for how to setup personal site url in individual user profile once for all

Answer (score 2):

Add one Navigation link in your site which will point to the below URL:

```
https://<domain>-my.sharepoint.com/
```

**Note**: Change `<domain>` with your domain name.

**Additional Reference**:

1. [Customize the navigation on your SharePoint site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca).

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, but i am looking for how to setup personal site url in individual user profile

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell with CSOM or PnP PowerShell to update user profile properties.

A demo(PnP PowerShell) for updating a user property of a user:

```
#Config Variables
$AdminSiteURL = "https://xxx-admin.sharepoint.com"
$UserAccount= "Peter@xxx.com"

#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $AdminSiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)

#sharepoint online powershell update user profile property
Set-PnPUserProfileProperty -Account $UserAccount -PropertyName "Department" -Value "Operations - IT"
```

[SharePoint Online: Update User Profile Properties using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/01/sharepoint-online-update-user-profile-properties-using-powershell.html)